# Hacky documentation website search using either Perl or Python

Tags: javascript, python, perl, web, search

I have a test coming up where we have been provided full access to perl5 and python3 documentation. The problem the search feature in these documentations have been disabled as I guess it uses the internet to get results.[Exam environment, the internet is disabled]

I was hoping if I could write a hacky/ make-shift website documentation search to use during the exam.[I will learn and reproduce the code in exam and then use it NOT carry it on a device or something]

All the resources available online either reference external libraries or implement sophisticated ranking searches. Which is not practical for my purpose.

Details:

1. The documentation is hosted on the university domain
2. I have access to Perl5, Python3.6, python2.7, Vanilla JS

Requirement:

1. Search website for the keyword
2. display links based on the frequency of the said keyword

I would appreciate if you could point me to appropriate resources or give advice as to how to approach this.

**EDIT 1:**
I am on some sort of a private network. So WGET works to pull the website but links pointing to external download sources are disabled, I can only access links that point to locations within the docs.

**EDIT 2:**
I ended up using perldocs had a hard time looking for stuff but it was better than alternatives and best available.

Comment: Note that you can use perldoc and pydoc from the command line. However, some Perl installations omit the documentation, and pydoc is only a frontend for the `help()` system – it only shows the docstrings and introspects the structure of modules/classes, but does not show the full documentation.

Comment: `perldoc` command line tool gives access to Perl docs. Depending on command-line options, it can bring up specific perl doc pages, docs on modules, specific functions or special vars.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build the docs yourself with sphinx?

Just take python repo https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Doc and run the sphinx, then you can also apply any theme you like: python-docs-theme, rtd-theme.

Comment: I will get the copy on docs during the exam. I cannot take material into the exam.

Comment: You should also be able to rebuilt the docs from sources because sphinx web contains it's sources in `_sources` eg: https://docs.python.org/3/_sources/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you would be to download the docs for offline use;

https://docs.python.org/3.6/archives/python-3.6.7-docs-html.zip

You can then search the documentation offline aswell.

Comment: Download option has been blocked. I can do wget and stuff no internet access and since the link you provided is hosted outside, I don't have access to it.

Comment: how can you "do wget and stuff " without internet access?

Comment: what does "Download option has been blocked" mean?

Comment: can you not just download the html docs then just upload the docs to the uni domain?

Comment: I am on some sort of a private network. So WGET works to pull the website hosted on the private uni server. But links pointing to external download sources are disabled(like download python docs link), I can only access links that point to locations within the docs.

Comment: You could learn a basic implementation of... http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/search-engine-python/